# Adding actual products to a variable product as Add-ons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, product

I am trying to add actual products I have added to a variable product as add-ons in WooCommerce.

There are 2 reasons for this:

- Mostly everything on my website is subscription based, with the variable product having specific SKUs and the add-ons having their SKUs, but then needing them both to be monthly subscriptions.

I tried a product add-on plugin but it won't do monthly subscriptions, it only does one time checkout fees and I cant add skus.

I tried grouped products, but it leaves the page when I try to select variations and doesn't go back. Also I can't select or deselect the "add-ons"

Need some direction here to some plugins or options.